# C# get settings from a file

Tags: c#, settings

In c# how can I read the text from a file, then apply a setting from in my program. 
Config.dat:

```
autoquit = true
```

Then if autoquit is true then it'll automatically quit. I know there are built in settings but I would like to know how to convert the settings from within the project to a file & then load the settings when you start the program.

Comment: If you have lots of configuration settings it would probably be worth using XML serialisation as this makes it easier to store structured data.

Comment: For simple key/value I'd personally use INI files

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the App.config file and the built-in support for getting settings from it?

Comment: @Lea we don't use INI files in .NET

Comment: @kirk I only meant the file extension. If the file is split and is only key value pairs then it seems a logical format. Plus you benefit from syntax highlighting in some editors

Comment: @kirk though I do agree that the XML configuration is the way to go

Comment: .NET has a huge amount of functionality around the `System.Configuration` namespace which starts with XML-based configuration files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx INI file to me means a flat text file. I've never seen a .NET project that didn't use the standard XML structure; it's really the only way to go. I'd refuse to work on a project that didn't use it - not because it's necessary, but because anyone who refuses to use it is sure to have made other completely illogical & frustrating design decisions.

Comment: It is possible that the developer has inherited the mess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add an `<appSettings>` section to your configuration file.

If you don't have a config file, right click on your project, click 'Add', click 'New Item....' and selection application (or web) configuration file from the 'General' tab.

Add a setting to your configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Autoquit" value="True" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and then in your code, something like

```
var autoquit = (bool)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Autoquit"];
```

You'll need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` to access the `ConfigurationManager` class.

This is the standard, accepted way to store configuration settings. Do not create text files and read string values from them. You can store typed values in the settings section but if you do some research you'll find out how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

`File.ReadAllText()` will read text from a file. You could then parse the file with regular expressions, `string.Split()`, or something else.

You'll get a better answer than this if you show us what you have so far...

Comment: The `file class` docs may help him too - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: -1 Don't store settings in plain text files in .NET - use the standard configuration patterns.

Comment: Clearly there is never a time when you might need to store configuration outside of app.config. I've always hated being able to write user preferences to disk. Thanks for setting me straight, Kirk...

Comment: Why would you write you user preferences in a text file when you can use the configuration classes? When the question clearly states a application setting, why recommend anything other than app.config?

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigurationManager class is very helpful for this sort of operation.  Refer to this for an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

You'll find that there are a lot of advantages to using a standard strategy like this.

Comment: I find Microsoft examples are not very helpful.